# Real world time in a SimCity day on various speeds

Tags: simcity-2013

Does anyone have the figures for amount of real world time it takes to pass a single day in SimCity on the three speed settings?

Comment: ... Out of curiosity, how do those speed settings work if you're one city in a multiplayer region?

Comment: @Shadur each city runs in its own time.  Some cities may be running Turtle, while others are running Llama.  Some cities may be paused.  Cities are frozen in time when the mayor isn't there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surely it should be simple enough to figure out.

I ran a stopwatch to figure out how much real world time it takes for some nice number of in-game time.

```
Turtle:  30s real-world / 15m in-game -> 1s real-world / 30s in-game
Llama:   30s real-world /  1h in-game -> 1s real-world /  2m in-game
Cheetah: 30s real-world /  2h in-game -> 1s real-world /  4m in-game
```

So from Turtle to Llama, it's a **4x** speedup. From Llama to Cheetah is **2x** speedup.  From Turtle to Cheetah is **8x** speedup.

So you can do the math if you want to figure out various times.

For llama speed:

```
Real-World time for 1 in-game day (the full day/night cycle):
1 day in-game = 24h ig = 24*30s rw = 720s rw = 12m real-world

Real-World time for 1 in-game month (1 month ig = 1 day ig):
1 month in-game = 1 day ig = 12m real-world

Real-World time for 1 in-game year:
1 year in-game = 12 months ig = 12*12m rw = 144m rw = 2h24m real-world
```

Then scale accordingly if you want to figure out the Turtle and Cheetah times.

Comment: Surely 1 month in-game is ~30 * 1 day in-game, so ~360 minutes or 6 hours in real time. One year would then be 72 hours, or 3 days.

Comment: No, a month of in-game time is equivalent to a single full day/night cycle. And it's better that way. I don't want to wait 3 days worth of gaming time of (what I consider) normal speed just for the game to go through an entire year.

Comment: So... there's no difference between a day and a month in Sim City?

Comment: Weird, it would seem that there's not. Sort of defeats the point of having months/years...